# Custom filter in ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I am not understanding how to use ransack properly.

I have a equipments class, which a method called "available" which do some stuff to decide if the thing is or isn't available returning true or false.

What i wish is to create a ransack filter, that let me filter for only available equipments. 
Since available isn't a real db parameter, i don't have an available_eq

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :available, "Available: "  %><br />
  <%= f.select :available_eq, [["Yes", true], ["Not", false]], {:include_blank => "All"}, {:class => "search-field"} %>
</div>
```

How i include this thing?

Comment: Have you tried the RegEx Builder in Ransack?  Also, you asked the question with Avaliable? but in your code, you show: Avaliable: ..  Why the difference?  Also, I notice you spelled Avaliable incorrectly in your code.

Comment: That's because my code wasn't originally written in English, i translated for stackoverflow. (poor as you notice)
I let this problem in the ice for some time. I tried changing the name of the method from available? to available at some point, before i learn about ransacker.
I will fix those things